# Swing to Javafx conversion

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx

I am not sure if this is a dumb question but I need help with this program I was creating. I wanted to make a login screen to this instant messenger app, which I already have created but I made it in javaFX. The problem is that since this instant messenger app is old, I created it with swing. Since there are no scenes in swing and there are in javafx, then when I hit login I would normally change the scene and that's it. That is why I am changing this program to javafx from swing but I am getting a couple of errors, if anyone is kind enough to tell me what I did wrong I would be grateful. Thanks and sorry for being so redundant, remember i'm just a beginner in 9th grade.

The exact error is in the line 56

```
The method ActionListener(new ActionListener(){}) is undefined for the type TextField
```

```
package messengerClient;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ClientFX extends Application {

    private TextField userText;
    private TextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;
    private Socket connection;

    Stage window;
    Scene scene1,scene2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Client - Instant Messenger!");
        ClientFX juan = new ClientFX("127.0.0.1");
        juan.startRunning();
  }
  //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ClientFX(String host){
        serverIP = host;
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(chatWindow);
        userText = new TextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.ActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            );
        BorderPane layout1 = new BorderPane();
        layout1.setTop(userText);
        layout1.setCenter(chatWindow);
        chatWindow = new TextArea();
        scene2 = new Scene(layout1,500,300);
        window.setScene(scene2);
        window.show();
    }

    //CONNECT TO SERVER
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){
            showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeCrap();
        }
    }

    //CONNECT TO SERVER
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
        showMessage("You have succesfully connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    //SET UP STREAMS TO SEND AND RECIVE MESSAGES
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\nYour streams are now ready to go! \n");
    }

    //WHILE CHATTING WITH THE SERVER
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        ableToType(true);
        do{
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException){
                showMessage("\nI do not know that object type");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("Server - END"));
    }

    //CLOSE THE STREAMS AND THE SOCKETS 
    private void closeCrap(){
        showMessage("\nClosing streams and the sockets down...");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //SEND MESSAGES TO THE SERVER
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            chatWindow.appendText("\nThat data type cannot be sent, sorry!");
        }
    }

    //UPDATE CHAT WINDOW
    private void showMessage(final String m){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        chatWindow.appendText(m);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //GIVES USER PERMISION TO TYPE INTO THE TEXT BOX
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        userText.setEditable(tof);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're asking about errors or exceptions, **always** post the full error/exception message in with your question, and indicate which lines of code are involved. These messages are super important and usually tell you **exactly** what you're doing wrong, leading you to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: That you didn't do this suggests that you're posting a question without first reading how to do so on this site, something that you don't want to do, not if you want a good reception here and decent answers. So please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and their answers will be better making your future experiences here better

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question, just edit it to include what errors you see. Then we will be able to help.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels =  Sorry I just created my account, I edited the question I hope that helps you help me

Comment: @nhouser9 = the errors are now included and thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are mixing swing and javafx. You are importing both:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
...
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
```

For example in the ClientFX constructor you are trying to add a javax.swing.JTextField (a swing component) to a javafx.scene.BorderPane (a javafx component). The JTextField does not extend javafx.scene.Node, therefore it cannot be given to BorderPane.setTop(Node).

Basically for any swing component (often start with J, JTextField, JTextArea etc.) find the javafx equivalent (for example javafx.scene.control.TextField, javafx.scene.control.TextArea) and learn how to use them (they will have a different api).
In the end you should not have an import statement for java.awt or javax.swing.

#### Update

As already said you need to learn how to use the new fx apis. Not only the package names, classes and methods change, but also maybe programming concepts.
To port your JTextField behaviour you use a TextField and call the setOnAction method with an EventHandler implementation (very similar to the swing concept):

```
userText.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event)
    {
    //        
    }
});
```

Comment: = Thanks alot, but I just edited the code and got another error

Comment: I got them to both work together (javaFX and swing) but now i got that error^

Comment: you should not try to get them work together. The ActionListener for example is again a awt/swing component. Get rid of swing and use the equivalent javafx components. The technologies are by design not compatible

Comment: Its just that if I take them off I get even more errors in the invoke commands

Comment: The method ActionListener(new ActionListener(){}) is undefined for the type TextField

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoLeyva You are confusing yourself... This `TextField` is from JavaFX and it doesn't have `ActionListener`, you can only use `setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>())`.

Comment: I updated my answer. However you should try to follow my advice, and learn how to use the new api. Search stuff like "javafx tutorial" or "how to use javafx TextField" and not just delete the swing components. My advice is to **replace** them with the javafx equivalents